Vuetify v-text-field v-menu width issue
When I use prepend-inner-icon,append-inner-icon, or both with a v-text-field, the v-menu width is not full. However, if I don't use these icons, the v-menu width fits perfectly. I want the width to be full even when using prepend-inner-icon, append-inner-icon, or both. Can anyone help me solve this?
Using append-inner-icon & prepend-inner-icon

Without using append-inner-icon & prepend-inner-icon

I want the width to be full even when using prepend-inner-icon, append-inner-icon, or both.

I recommend providing a Vuetify playground so that people can help you fix it faster. But should be doable by using some CSS and the right deep selector.

Do you mean v-select, v-autocomplete, or v-combobox? I agree with @kissu, it's better if you could provide a playground.

Have you tried with the v-select?
It seems it doesn't has the issue you mentioned, see demo for more detail:
https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#eNqVUdFqgzAU/ZWLDLpBsz7sTVyhlK0voy97Km2hUW/brDGRJLqB+O9L4tSs0MEe1Nxzzz33eLJtIq2y2aIsH+sKozhKDBYlpwbnOwGQ1CSTHOyjn3fR0y7yqMc1csxMVwLUpJA5ckv6waO+E5+ZMBY/3DVd61EbK99OYQBomqr2EIwwa8It9N8RdyUxzHB0e5zKVa+mvHI9Jzi2OE29s/crZyUqzbRBYYjz2MMKTaUEkelH8H+aiRNHwpnAYVxhiSInTAhUhGVS2B1FzshZFoOxeTILo/KlTdPGmMyCpG2pM8VK4/PFr1IqAzkeacUNNJ1UTg29f+ir3udYW5N+TwwN+HBimLxyqVhOJ1NwkTjgbQLtdBzxCcewHRH4z3hIXqFUJxaQV4vb5DWmiupLwF6/3GYvKWdHqUSovvxT/RM2Ul0C9c1v9n44t92ha9oimQ03EbVTUXHuX/tvxpnzug==
